# YADCF - Trigger filter button in column header

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I have a DataTable with dynamically added columns and data. YADCF is working great, but having all the filters showing at once is too much for the UI. I've seen solutions that have a filter icon next to each header title, and when you click the filter icon, it brings up a tooltip-style filter UI. I'm not sure I can get the YADCF filter into a tooltip, but I do at least need to hide the filters until that button is clicked. Is there an example of this anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen ppl achieving this behavior with yadcf but it requires additional code as yadcf does not have this feature out of the box yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Create a button first then add jQuery.

```
$('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').hide();
$(#myButton).click(function() {
    $('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').toggle();
});
```